# ng-grid enable edit for newly added rows

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am adding new rows to existing data. I would like that all the new rows added should be editable while the original rows shown to the user should not be editable.

Here is [Plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/WM7Wq9suB1OdMQ4Qc8ix)

The new value cell is always editable (either original row or new row) however, the Time, Existing Value are only editable when a new row is inserted.

In the plnkr, select a row and click on 'Add row above' to add a new row.
(Other buttons don't work at this time)

Please let me know how I can do that.

Comment: Can anyone please answer or comment?